# Hide Simple Action Controller When The View Not Yet Saved

Tags: controller, hide, detailview, xaf

I'm new on XAF and actually not so good in english too.

I'm trying to create controller with Simple Action on it.
how do i **hide** this simple action on detailview while the view is new object or the view hasn't been saved.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that Object Saving and View Saving are two different things.

Objects are saved through the Save Action, in a View.

You can hide a SimpleAction using the [ActionBase.TargetObjectsCriteria](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/DevExpressExpressAppActionsActionBase_TargetObjectsCriteriatopic) property, by writing a criterion string that returns false when the object is new.

A new object check criteria reference can be found [here](http://dennisgaravsky.blogspot.com.br/2014/07/checking-if-object-is-new-or-not-within.html).

Also, here's a [sample code](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q440548).

Comment: Hei Erik, Thanks for the answer.
it works for me using a new object criteria reference.
Thanks a lot